# Default value given in ng-model is not selected in drop down

Tags: angularjs, html

I was trying simple select drop down in my app. Where I have set a default value in ng-model. But on load the drop down does not select the ng-model value.
Below are my codes:

HTML:

```
View <select  ng-model="viewby" ng-change="setItemsPerPage(viewby)"><option>3</option><option>5</option><option>10</option><option>20</option><option>30</option><option>40</option><option>50</option></select> records at a time.
```

Js:

```
$scope.viewby=3             
  $scope.setItemsPerPage = function(num) {
    console.log( num);
  }
```

Here ng-change is working perfectly.
Here '3'  should be selected on load. I tried ng-init and selected='selected'  also and both are not working. Any suggestion will help.--thanks

Answer (score 0):

In angular, Better way is to define the options as array and bind them, so that ng-model will get updated.

**JS:**

```
 $scope.model = 30;
 $scope.options = [10, 20, 30,40,50];
```

**HTML**

```
 <select  ng-change="setItemsPerPage(model)" ng-model="model" ng-options="value for value in options"></select>
```

[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/1qo2q5yr/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like below snippet. Here default selected option was ***20***, you can change it to your need.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedOption = 20;
  $scope.setItemsPerPage = function(num) {
    console.log(num);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">

    View

    <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="setItemsPerPage(selectedOption)">
      <option>3</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>20</option>
      <option>30</option>
      <option>40</option>
      <option>50</option>
    </select>

    records at a time.

  </div>

</div>
```